# Simple lightweight object pool - follow-up

Tags: java

This question is in response to the code review here: [Simple lightweight object pool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115564/simple-lightweight-object-pool). Please visit the original question for background.

I have taken on board all the suggestions made and carefully amended the code in response. As the answer is in two parts: one being the code review and that other being suggestions, I will respond to each separately. Additionally, I have added the code to Github [code review changes](https://github.com/atheedom/SimpleConfigurablePool/tree/master) and [suggestions](https://github.com/atheedom/SimpleConfigurablePool/tree/feature/withSupplier).

1. I have made the interface define the pool contract and removed the `@FunctionalInterface` as it served no purpose.
2. The abstract class constructs the pool using only constructors and it has a private method that performs the initialization.
3. The `pool` object is now encapsulated and properties of the pool such as its `size` are accessed via methods in the abstract class.
4. The method `borrowObject()` is now named `acquire()` and `returnObject()` has been renamed `surrender()`.
5. The pool now has a life-cycle status of `STARTING`, `STARTED`, `STOPPING` or `STOPPED`. This prevents access to the pool while it is being destroyed/has been destroyed. The `destroy()` method removes an item from the queue. This is used by the monitor to maintain the pool size when it grows beyond `maxIdle`. Also it is used by `destroyPool()` to remove objects from the pool.
6. It is no longer possible to specify the queue implementation. The pool uses the `BlockingQueue` implementation. This prevents the client using a non-thread safe implementation.
7. The shadowed `pool` variable has been removed.

Questions:

1. You mentioned the use of `Closable`. Can you elaborate, please?
2. I have removed the need to make the queue access thread-safe as the `BlockingQueue` takes care of it internally. However I would like to know how I would implement thread safety. This is an area that I would like to improve my knowledge of.
3. I have implemented a pool life-cycle status. Has this been done well?

Here is the changed code:

```
public interface Pool<T> {
    T acquire() throws Exception;
    void surrender(T item) throws Exception;
}
```

The implementation of the interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractObjectPool<T> implements Pool<T> {

public enum PoolState {
    STARTING, STARTED, STOPPING, STOPPED
}

private PoolState currentStatus;
private BlockingQueue<T> pool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private int pollTimeout;
private int poolSize;

protected AbstractObjectPool() {
    this.poolSize = 100;
    initialize();
}

protected AbstractObjectPool(int poolSize) {
    this.poolSize = poolSize;
    initialize();
}

protected AbstractObjectPool(int poolSize, int pollTimeout) {
    this.pollTimeout = pollTimeout;
    this.poolSize = poolSize;
    initialize();
}


/**
 * Initialise the pool and populate it with poolSize number of objects
 */
private void initialize() {
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STARTING);
    if (poolSize < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pool Size must be at least 1");
    }
    while (pool.size() < poolSize) {
        pool.add(createObject());
    }
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STARTED);
}

/**
 * Sets the pools current status
 *
 * @param currentStatus the pool's current status
 */
private void updatePoolStatus(PoolState currentStatus) {
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
}


/**
 * Returns the current pool size
 *
 * @return number of objects in the pool
 */
public int getCurrentPoolSize() {
    return pool.size();
}

/**
 * Is the pool null
 *
 * @return true if null otherwise false
 */
public boolean isPoolNull() {
    return pool == null;
}


/**
 * Returns the status of the current pool.
 *
 * @return the current pool status
 */
public PoolState poolState() {
    return this.currentStatus;
}


/**
 * Gets the next free object from the pool.
 * <p/>
 * Different strategies can be implemented to deal with a
 * situation where the pool doesn't contain any objects.
 * <p/>
 * Some possible options:
 * <p/>
 * 1. a new object will be created and given to the caller of this method.
 * 2. a PoolDepletionException is thrown
 * 3. wait for a specified time for an object to be returned
 *
 * @return T borrowed object
 * @throws PoolDepletionException thrown if the pool has been depleted
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public T acquire() throws Exception {
    checkPoolStatus();
    T t = pool.poll(pollTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if (t == null) {
        throw new PoolDepletionException("The pool is empty and was not replenished within timeout limits.");
    }

    return t;
}


/**
 * Returns object back to the pool.
 * <p/>
 * Possible implementation may include code to clean/reset the
 * object to initial values.
 *
 * @param object object to be returned
 */
public void surrender(T object) throws Exception {
    checkPoolStatus();
    if (object == null) {
        return;
    }
    this.pool.offer(object);
}


/**
 * Creates a new object.
 *
 * @return T new object
 */
protected abstract T createObject();


/**
 * Adds object to the pool.
 *
 * @return true if added successfully otherwise false
 */
public boolean add() throws Exception {
    checkPoolStatus();
    return pool.add(createObject());
}


/**
 * Checks that the pool is running and ready for use otherwise it throws an exception
 *
 * @throws Exception thrown if pool not ready or shutting down
 */
private void checkPoolStatus() throws Exception {
    if (poolState() != PoolState.STARTED) throw new Exception("Pool not ready or stopped");
}

/**
 * Destroys an object.
 */
public void destroy() {
    pool.poll();
}


/**
 * Destroys the entire pool.
 */
public void destroyPool() {
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STOPPING);
    while (pool != null && !pool.isEmpty()) {
        destroy();
    }
    pool = null;
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STOPPED);
}

}
```

An example of an implementation of a fixed pool:

```
public class JsonParserFixedPool extends AbstractObjectPool<JsonParserAndMapper> {

public JsonParserFixedPool(int poolSize, int poolTimeout) {
    super(poolSize, poolTimeout);
}

public JsonParserFixedPool(int poolSize) {
    super(poolSize);
}

/**
 * Creates a BOON JSON parser object.
 *
 * @return a new BOON JSON parser object
 */
@Override
protected JsonParserAndMapper createObject() {
    return new JsonParserFactory().useAnnotations().usePropertiesFirst().create();
}

}
```

An example of usage:

```
jsonParserFixedPool = new JsonParserFixedPool(10);
JsonParserAndMapper jsonParserAndMapper = jsonParserFixedPool.acquire();
jsonParserFixedPool.surrender(jsonParserAndMapper);
```

Now to the suggestions:

1. The constructor now accepts a `Supplier` that provides a new object.
2. I decided to keep the monitor. I like to give the client the option to have a pool with or without a monitor by choosing which abstract class to implement. I also felt that this logic should be separate from the `acquire()` method, trying to follow separation of concerns principle.
3. I have added a default `handleDepletion()` method. This allows the client to implement their own logic for handling pool depletion.
4. I decided not to include the `lazyAdd()` method. I felt that the monitor functionality and the `handleDepletion()` method take care of pool replenishment, although I like the idea of using a thread to create a new object.

Questions:

You mention "...actually implement the Supplier interface yourself". Do you mean something like this? The abstract class implements the `Supplier` interface and the concrete class implements the `get()` method like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractObjectPool<T> implements Pool<T>, Supplier<T> { ... }

@Override
public JsonParserAndMapper get() {
    return new JsonParserFactory().useAnnotations().usePropertiesFirst().create();
}
```

Now for the code based on the suggestions:

Same interface as above and the following abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractObjectPool<T> implements Pool<T> {

public enum PoolState {
    STARTING, STARTED, STOPPING, STOPPED
}

private PoolState currentStatus;
private BlockingQueue<T> pool= new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private int pollTimeout;
private final int poolSize;
private final Supplier<T> supplier;

protected AbstractObjectPool(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.poolSize = 100;
    initialize();
}

protected AbstractObjectPool(Supplier<T> supplier, int poolSize) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.poolSize = poolSize;
    initialize();
}

protected AbstractObjectPool(Supplier<T> supplier, int poolSize, int pollTimeout) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.pollTimeout = pollTimeout;
    this.poolSize = poolSize;
    initialize();
}


/**
 * Initialise the pool and populate it with poolSize number of objects
 */
private void initialize() {
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STARTING);
    if (poolSize < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pool Size must be at least 1");
    }
    while (pool.size() < poolSize) {
        pool.add(supplier.get());
    }
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STARTED);
}

/**
 * Sets the pools current status
 *
 * @param currentStatus the pool's current status
 */
private void updatePoolStatus(PoolState currentStatus) {
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
}


/**
 * Returns the current pool size
 *
 * @return number of objects in the pool
 */
public final int getCurrentPoolSize() {
    return pool.size();
}

/**
 * Is the pool null
 *
 * @return true if null otherwise false
 */
public final boolean isPoolNull() {
    return pool == null;
}


/**
 * Returns the status of the current pool.
 *
 * @return the current pool status
 */
public final PoolState poolState() {
    return this.currentStatus;
}


/**
 * Gets the next free object from the pool.
 * <p/>
 * Different strategies can be implemented to deal with a
 * situation where the pool doesn't contain any objects.
 * <p/>
 * Some possible options:
 * <p/>
 * 1. a new object will be created and given to the caller of this method.
 * 2. a PoolDepletionException is thrown
 * 3. wait for a specified time for an object to be returned
 *
 * @return T borrowed object
 * @throws PoolDepletionException thrown if the pool has been depleted
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public final T acquire() throws Exception {
    checkPoolStatus();
    T t = pool.poll(pollTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if (t == null) {
        return handleDepletion(supplier);
    }

    return t;
}


/**
 * Returns object back to the pool.
 * <p/>
 * Possible implementation may include code to clean/reset the
 * object to initial values.
 *
 * @param object object to be returned
 */
public final void surrender(T object) throws Exception {
    checkPoolStatus();
    if (object == null) {
        return;
    }
    this.pool.offer(object);
}


/**
 * Adds object to the pool.
 *
 * @return true if added successfully otherwise false
 */
public final boolean add() throws Exception {
    checkPoolStatus();
    return pool.add(supplier.get());
}

/**
 * What to do if there's nothing to return within the expected time. options
 * are to create an instance manually, or alternatively throw an exception.
 * returning null would be a bad idea, though.
 *
 * @param supplier
 *            the supplier that feeds this pool - can be used to get a
 *            guaranteed, but slow instance.
 * @return the value for the client to use
 * @throws PoolDepletionException
 *             if that is how the pool instance should respond.
 */
protected T handleDepletion(Supplier<T> supplier) throws PoolDepletionException{
    throw new PoolDepletionException("The pool is empty and was not replenished within timeout limits.");
}

/**
 * Checks that the pool is running and ready for use otherwise it throws an exception
 *
 * @throws Exception thrown if pool not ready or shutting down
 */
private void checkPoolStatus() throws Exception {
    if (poolState() != PoolState.STARTED) throw new Exception("Pool not ready or stopped");
}

/**
 * Destroys an object.
 */
public void destroy() {
   pool.poll();
}


/**
 * Destroys the entire pool.
 */
public void destroyPool() {
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STOPPING);
    while (pool != null && !pool.isEmpty()) {
        destroy();
    }
    pool = null;
    updatePoolStatus(PoolState.STOPPED);
}

}
```

An extension of the AbstractObjectPool:

```
public abstract class FlexibleObjectPool<T> extends AbstractObjectPool<T> {

private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

private float poolSizeFactor = 0.8f;

/**
 * Construct a flexible pool with default configuration values.
 *
 * @param supplier the supplier that creates a new instance of the object
 * @param poolSize the initial size of the pool
 */
public FlexibleObjectPool(Supplier<T> supplier, int poolSize) {
    super(supplier, poolSize);
    int minIdle = (int) (poolSize * poolSizeFactor);
    int maxIdle = (int) (poolSize * (1 + (1 - poolSizeFactor)));
    provokePoolMonitor(minIdle, maxIdle, 3000);
}

/**
 * Construct a flexible pool.
 * <p/>
 * Set starting pool size equal to the average of the minIdle and maxIdle.
 *
 * @param supplier           the supplier that creates a new instance of the object
 * @param minIdle            the minimum pool size that the monitor should attempt to maintain
 * @param maxIdle            the maximum pool size that the monitor should attempt to maintain
 * @param validationInterval the interval at which to fire the monitor
 */
public FlexibleObjectPool(Supplier<T> supplier, int minIdle, int maxIdle, int validationInterval) {
    super(supplier, (maxIdle + minIdle) / 2);
    provokePoolMonitor(minIdle, maxIdle, validationInterval);
}

public FlexibleObjectPool(Supplier<T> supplier, FlexiblePoolConfig config) {
    super(supplier, (config.maxIdle + config.minIdle) / 2);
    provokePoolMonitor(config.minIdle, config.maxIdle, config.validationInterval);
}


/**
 * Checks pool conditions in a separate thread.
 * <p/>
 * If pool size rises to above maxIdle then the number of objects
 * deleted is equal to the excess over the minIdle.
 * <p/>
 * If pool size drops below minIdle new objects are created to
 * bring it up to the minIdle level.
 *
 * @param minIdle            minimum number of objects idling in the object pool
 * @param maxIdle            maximum number of objects idling in the object pool
 * @param validationInterval time in milli-seconds for periodical checking of minIdle / maxIdle conditions in a separate thread.
 *                           When the number of objects is less than minIdle, missing instances will be created.
 *                           When the number of objects is greater than maxIdle, excess instances will be removed.
 */
protected void provokePoolMonitor(final int minIdle, final int maxIdle, int validationInterval) {
    if (minIdle < 1 || minIdle > maxIdle) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minIdle must be at least 1, and at least equal to maxIdle");
    }
    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        int size = getCurrentPoolSize();
        if (size < minIdle) {
            int sizeToBeAdded = minIdle - size;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeToBeAdded; i++) {
                try {
                    add();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (size > maxIdle) {
            int sizeToBeRemoved = size - maxIdle;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeToBeRemoved; i++) {
                destroy();
            }
        }

    }, validationInterval, validationInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}


/**
 * Shutdown this pool's executor service and deletes the object pool.
 */
public void destroyPool() {

    if (executorService != null) {
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService = null;
    }

    // Destroys the entire pool.
    super.destroyPool();
}


public class FlexiblePoolConfig {

    protected final int minIdle;
    protected final int maxIdle;
    protected final int validationInterval;

    public FlexiblePoolConfig(final int minIdle, final int maxIdle, final int validationInterval) {
        this.minIdle = minIdle;
        this.maxIdle = maxIdle;
        this.validationInterval = validationInterval;
    }

}
}
```

An example of a concrete implementation:

```
public class JsonParserFlexiblePool extends FlexibleObjectPool<JsonParserAndMapper> {

private static Supplier<JsonParserAndMapper> createJSONParserAndMapper() {
    return () -> new JsonParserFactory().useAnnotations().usePropertiesFirst().create();
}

public JsonParserFlexiblePool() {
    super(createJSONParserAndMapper(), 20);
}

public JsonParserFlexiblePool(int poolSize) {
    super(createJSONParserAndMapper(), poolSize);
}

public JsonParserFlexiblePool(int poolSize, int pollTimeout) {
    super(createJSONParserAndMapper(), poolSize, pollTimeout, 0);
}

public JsonParserFlexiblePool(int minIdle, int maxIdle, int validationInterval) {
    super(createJSONParserAndMapper(), minIdle, maxIdle, validationInterval);
}

public JsonParserFlexiblePool(FlexiblePoolConfig flexiblePoolConfig) {
    super(createJSONParserAndMapper(), flexiblePoolConfig);
}

}
```